# refresh label not working correctly javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a problem with a refresh on a Label. 
I have an function like this :

```
    public void majMontantPaye(Double montantPaye) {
    System.out.println("montant paye : "+montantPaye);

    setMontantPaye(this.montantPaye+montantPaye);

    Platform.runLater(() -> labelMontantPaye.setText(String.format("%.2f", this.montantPaye)+Messages.getMessage("0052")));
}
```

And My function is call by an API. This API communicate with a machine who allow to insert coin. And my function must to show the sum insert in the machine.

The problem is, when I insert a lot of coin in the same time in the machine, my function is correctly call every coin detected, so the `System.out.println("montant paye : "+montantPaye);` is correctly show  every coin detected, BUT the Label "labelMontantPaye" is not refresh to every coin detected. Just on finish with the total sum.

I guess that the UI is not correctly refresh but I don't know how refresh correctly my Label.

Help please and sorry for mistake, i'm french.

Comment: How is that method called? Perhaps on the application thread? Furthermore is `Messages.getMessage("0052")` a long-running operation? Are there synchronized blocks/methods that could block this operation until some long-running code is executed on a different thread?

Comment: My function is executed in a different thread. I have a `if(Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) { MainApp.getInstance.mainControllerLgetListeAchatController.majMontantPaye(_resteDu); } else { Platform.runLater(() -> MainApp.getInstance.mainControllerLgetListeAchatController.majMontantPaye(_resteDu); }); } `

Comment: Well with `runLater`you queue the task into the FXApplicationThread. But when you have many "events" you will only see the last result. (And maybe previous ones for a short time). If you really want to see the results inbetween i can't give you a solution now since there is no `runAndWait` like in SwingUtilities

Comment: So actually you execute it on the the JavaFX Application thread. That's what your comment shows.

Comment: For the coin detection you run an infinity Thread?Describe a little bit the logic so we can help.I mean how you work with the Threads generally.Remember not to run no UI things on JavaFX Thread.

Comment: Yes for the coin detection, it's an infinity Thread. The problem is that I don't work in the logic but the UI.

Comment: Benj to send a message to another user you have to user @UserName or the other user can't see any messages that you have send.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the logic below:

> As mentioned in the comments:
>    Using Platform.runLater(...) you queue the task into the `JavaFXThread`. But when you have many "events" you will only see the last result. (And maybe previous ones for a short time).
>
> Use a [BlockingQueue](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html) to store each coin that is inserted.Use the method below(also have a look at the tutorial for the available methods,here i am using put which is blocking the current thread if a maximum of coins are inserted into the Queue,if you don't want this set the maximum to something like 500.000):

```
public void insertCoin(//maybe the kind of coin){
      //add the coin into the BlockingQueue
      blockingQueue.put(//coin);
}
```

> Use a `Thread` which is running an infinity loop.The Thread is waking up
>   every time a new coin is inserted and when that is done , that Thread
>   waits `JavaFXThread` to refresh the Label Text:

```
new Thread(() -> {

        //Run an infinity Thread
        while (true) {

            // Blocks until the queue has really any coins inserted
            blockingQueue.get();

            // Synchronize with javaFX thread
            CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                label.setText(....);
                latch.countDown();
            });

            // Block the Current Thread until the text is refreshed from
            // JavaFX Thread
            latch.await();

        }
}).start();
```